# Encountering "requires_payment_method" Error When Implementing Stripe Payment Method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

## I am encountering an issue while integrating the Stripe payment method into my website. The error message I'm receiving is "requires_payment_method". Below, I've provided the relevant JavaScript, HTML, and Python (Django) logic for handling payments.

````
`<script>
    var stripe = Stripe('my_stripe_public_key');

    function submitPaymentForm() {
        var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder').value;
        var cardElement = elements.create('card');

        stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                console.error(result.error.message);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('stripeToken').value = result.token.id;
                document.form_payment.submit();
            }
        });
    }
</script>`
```
`



def checkout_payment(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      
    payment_method_token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
    print(payment_method_token)
    cardholder = request.POST.get('cardholder')
    cardnumber = request.POST.get('cardnumber')
    expiration_month = request.POST.get('mm')
    expiration_year = request.POST.get('yy')
    csc = request.POST.get('csc')
    
    # payment_type =request.POST.get('payment_type')

    user = request.user
    cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user, is_ordered=False)
    cart_total = sum(float(item.product.discounted_price()) * item.quantity for item in cart_items)

    total = int(cart_total * 100)

    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    try:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
            email = request.user.email,
        )

      # Create PaymentIntent with retrieved payment method
        payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=total,
        currency='pkr',
        payment_method_types=["card"],
        
        customer=customer.id,
        description="Payment for items in cart",
        metadata={'integration_check': 'accept_a_payment'},
        )   

          # Check for successful payment
        if payment_intent.status == 'succeeded':
            print(payment_intent)
            return redirect('checkout_complete')
        else:
            # Handle failed payment
            print(f"Payment failed with status: {payment_intent.status}")
            messages.error(request, 'Payment failed. Please try again.')

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      messages.error(request, 'An error occurred while processing the payment. Please try again.')

  return render(request, 'checkout_payment.html')




Issue:
Upon submitting the payment form, I encounter the "requires_payment_method" error consistently. Despite ensuring that my Stripe public key is correctly set, I'm unable to identify the root cause of this error.

Expected Behavior:
I anticipate that the payment process will proceed smoothly upon form submission, without encountering any errors. Subsequently, the user should be redirected to the checkout complete page.

Additional Details:

Backend operations are managed using Django.
I've meticulously validated that all required fields (e.g., cardholder name, card number, expiration date, etc.) are accurately transmitted to the backend for processing.
Attempted Solutions:

Reviewed and cross-checked the integration of the Stripe API for any misconfigurations or errors.
Consulted various documentation sources and community forums to identify potential solutions, but have yet to find a resolution.
Specific Concerns:

Is there any particular aspect of the Stripe configuration that might lead to the "requires_payment_method" error?
Are there any common pitfalls or overlooked steps in the integration process that could be causing this issue?
Any insights, suggestions, or guidance on resolving this issue would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!
````

I anticipate that the payment process will proceed smoothly upon form submission, without encountering any errors. Subsequently, the user should be redirected to the checkout complete page.